# How do I configure a full height Angular Material Dialog that closes when clicking on the overlay?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript

In my popup window, all info and inputs are usually fully displayed when first triggering it, however, I have a textArea box that I can expand to whatever height. Upon expansion, I want the entire popup to scroll on the page, not just that particular div which holds the expanded textArea.

I'm using this bit of CSS to make my popup window full height and scrollable when I expand the textArea.

```
.cdk-global-overlay-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  overflow: auto;
  pointer-events: auto;  
  padding-top: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
```

Everything worked as intended with that bit of CSS, however, I noticed that the popup no longer closes when clicking the overlay, and it's due to the `pointer-events: auto`, but removing this bit of CSS brings me back to square one where the popup doesn't scroll with the page when I expand the textArea.

Any ideas on the quickest, cleanest way to have both behaviors?

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below style.

```
.cdk-global-overlay-wrapper {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    overflow: auto;
    pointer-events: auto;
    padding-top: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I popped that style in and the same pointer-events issue is appearing. I also have set disableClose: true. Any ideas?